# prettySociable IE issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to use the jQuery script prettySociable, which works fine in all other browsers except for IE - am using IE 8 and have tried testing it in compatibility mode to no avail. I've tried to figure out the errors, but can't seem to get them to work..

http://www.souliejolie.com/2010/test.php

^^ the 'demo' page which craps out in IE, but works in all other browsers.

If someone could help me out, that'd be great!
Thank you

Comment: PS the "don't copy" content alert() won't stop anyone that wants it - in fact I already have it just by visiting the site.

Comment: yeh i know it doesn't, nothing really does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

believe it or not, it was crapping out at

```
<meta name="description" ...
```

had to change it to

```
<meta name="Description" ....
```

:/

Comment: Is this related to IE's getElementById() bug?